# Which parts of Inferno Act 1 actually drop ilvl 63 items?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I start from the beginning, I don't seem to ever get any - am I just getting unlucky?  Does their drop rate change from the beginning of the act to the end?

Comment: The edits are an attempt to help improve your question, and in turn improve the content of our site. There is no reason to continually roll back a valid edit.

Comment: This is a community site and the edits are done with the aim of improving it for the community in general. Specifying "Post 1.0.3" in the title localizes the question to an invalid/redundant time frame. The game cannot be played prior to 1.0.3 anymore so there is no purpose in specifying that you are post 1.0.3. Please be understanding and desist the rollback war or further action may be taken concerning this matter.

Comment: The reason is because the answers will all become out of date in a later patch, and both this question and answer will likely become irrelevant.

Comment: [No edit wars.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/edit-wars-are-bad-dont-encourage-or-participate-in-them)

Comment: That is why answers are editable by the community. If an answer becomes out of date, it can be updated rather than needing a new question for every patch that changes this.

Comment: @fcrick By removing the "Post 1.0.3" this question will become timeless; a simple amendment to the answer will keep it current. By leaving it in, it runs the risk of being closed as Too Localized the second a new patch releases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Per Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5967657367?page=4#74):

> ***The chances of getting an item of each item level are even throughout an entire Act.*** The hotfix note provides "approximate" rates because there are minor variances based on item type, and the % listed is an approximate aggregate across all item types (for the item level in a specific Act).

In an effort to make the answer more general, I'll include the updated drop rates for all zones.  From the patch notes posted [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/Patch_103_Now_Available-6_19_2012#blog), the approximate drop rates for all zones are:

> **Hell - Act III and Act IV**
>
> - iLvl 61: 9%
> - iLvl 62: 1.9%
> - iLvl 63: 0%
>
> **Inferno - Act I**
>
> - iLvl 61: 17.7%
> - iLvl 62: 7.9%
> - ***iLvl 63: 2.0%*** (This answers your specific question)
>
> **Inferno - Act II**
>
> - iLvl 61: 18.6%
> - iLvl 62: 12.4%
> - iLvl 63: 4.1%
>
> **Inferno - Act III and Act IV**
>
> - iLvl 61: 24.1%
> - iLvl 62: 16.1%
> - iLvl 63: 8.0%

Given a 2% drop rate for Act I, you are probably just unlucky - or rather, ***you'd be very lucky if you got one***.

Comment: `There is no mention of any specific areas` right.  _that_ is what we all already know.  I'm looking for verification of this, specifically.  The patch notes even use the word _approximate_, which is why my question is more specific

Comment: They use "approximate" because there are still random numbers at work (the 2% drop chance). You're reading too much into the word.

Comment: I'm not reading anything into it - that's the point.  I'm looking for evidence-based answers, not ones based on assumptions or interpretation.

Comment: I've been down this road before. I don't believe you'll find a more credible answer than the patch notes, but if you do: congratulations. For credible analysis of why 2% is unlikely, read about the [gambler's fallacy](http://vegasclick.com/gambling/fallacy.html).

Comment: @fcrick you are talking about a *Blizzard* game; the information they've released is all we're going to get, and the information they've released is already in this answer. Blizzard will not ever state "X area has Y drop chance" because people would only farm that area. *[They want you to farm entire acts](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208/)* and have stated this more than once.

Comment: @ickleislands no, that's totally false.  You get information by collecting it.  Why does everyone upvote answers that are good answers to OTHER questions, not the one they are in...eg "Do ilvl 63 items drop in Act 1?" would be a fitting qn. for this answer.

Comment: @fcrick Read the link in my comment, Blizzard want you to farm entire acts, thus entire acts will have a reasonably similar drop rate throughout. If you want to go through the process of generating a suitable sample size based on tens of thousands of drops then by all means feel free, it will be a useful resource. If not, then go on the information that is available.

Comment: Today's hotfix updated the drop rates.  Source: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6214196/Diablo_III_Hotfixes_-_June_Updated_628-6_28_2012#blog

Comment: @ickleislands i have read that link.  It does not answer this question directly.  I am looking for an evidence-based answer, not what the majority of people on this site conclude is likely to be true based on Blizzard posts.  If a blizzard post directly answered this question, that is great, but to my knowledge there is no such answer.

Comment: @Fcrick Maybe something like this will suffice?  Blizzard CM: "The chances of getting an item of each item level are even throughout an entire Act."  http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5967657367?page=4#74

Comment: @bwarner Big props for finding that.  Blue posts are quite the diamond in the rough on such topics.  Hope you don't mind my quoting.

Answer (score 1):

The entirety of Act 1 Inferno has a 2% chance of dropping items with an ilvl of 63.  In fact, the drop rate of items with ilvls of 61, 62, and 63 are constant through the whole of each act.

See the [patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/6457499#items) for more information.

Comment: That is incorrect...take another look at the patch notes you just linked to. Items of ilvl 63 in Act 1 Inferno have a 2% chance of dropping.

Comment: `the drop rate of items with ilvls of 61, 62, and 63 are constant through the whole of each act` - any source of that claim?  Maybe they are implying that, but I've never seen it articulated.

Comment: @Kotsu: You're right, must have been looking at Act 3/4 Hell.  Updated the answer

Comment: @crick: That's a fair comment, but it also seems logical to me.  Not that acts are all that long if all you're doing is farming.

Answer (score 1):

I have found 2 Ilevel 63 items in Act 1 Inferno.

1 in The Weeping Hollow
and
1 in in a Defiled Crypt under the Cemetery of the forsaken

Both found during Skeleton King runs

and ofc not during the same run I did many runs before they dropped

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Act 1 inferno can drop item level 63 from the start to the end of the act.  I have received 11 item level 63 items since the change, playing the entire act a few times.

I've gotten one off of the trash right in front of New Tristram, before even going in the town.  I've gotten a few from the quest's that come before the blacksmith.  I've also gotten a few off of the Halls of Agony.

Note, I've never gotten one from the Warden or the Butcher, but I'm pretty sure that's just luck/bad luck.  All except for one has come from champ/elite packs (most recent one came off of a white mob in front of New Tristram).

Answer (score -1):

After the patch 1.04 update i went through all act I inferno 2 times with a solo demon hunter + mf/gf follower (templar), warded 450k gold per run (101% gf, 156% mf) and got some AH sales, making 1,2kk gold at all. I have droped a good yellow bow level 63 with 1090 dps + DEX + socket, in a elite pack on cemetery that turned into my primary weapon and the best bow i had ever droped. Also got some decent hand crossbows >770 dps with good stats and some armor level 61-63 that turned into my primary armor. It was very profitable. Only recoreded 2 deaths for some elite pack combinations. However that were no legendaries. Each run got about 4 hours.