# Do bosses drop a higher chance of iLv63 items?

Tags: diablo-iii

Don't get me wrong, I've read Blizzard's announcment on patch 1.0.3, and this post as well [Which parts of Inferno Act 1 actually drop ilvl 63 items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74448/which-parts-of-inferno-act-1-actually-drop-ilvl-63-items).

What I want to ask is that, do you get a **rarer drop versus elites/champions for bosses**? Because I have 220% magic find and I'm actually getting **more** rare drops from **elites/champions** (1 - 3) than a **boss** fight alone (1), and if there isn't any difference, I might as well start hunting for elites/champs than farming all the way to a boss in Inferno.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Blizzard want you to farm elite packs rather than bosses](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6262208/) and have adjusted the guaranteed drops from bosses and elite packs in the 1.0.3 patch:

**The Nephalem Difference**

> It’s no secret that our goal for the end-game item hunt is players hunting monsters packs, building to five stacks of Nephalem Valor, and then killing a boss. While we’re seeing a lot of that occurring, what we’re missing is people feeling like it’s worthwhile to continue onward after killing a boss.
>
> To help hit that goal we’re lowering the number of guaranteed Rare items on bosses when you have your full five stacks of Nephalem Valor from two guaranteed Rares to one guaranteed Rare (you still have a very good chance at multiple rares, it's just no longer guaranteed). In exchange, all champion and rare packs will now drop a bonus guaranteed Rare item when you have your full five stacks of Nephalem Valor. The change benefits players with more overall drops, and a reason to push to continue progressing.

Comment: To add something to this answer, the link also lists a table with the % chance of which an item with ilvl 63 will drop. I do believe an item dropped from a boss is as likely to be ilvl63 as an item dropped from a champion pack, however since bosses drop more items than champions - you are more likely to get one from a boss kill than a champion kill.

Comment: beautiful answer. also @issac, bosses do not drop more rares than champions. magics, yes, though.

Answer (score 3):

The bosses do not have a any higher percentage to drop higher item level then the other rate champion/elite monsters. According to the developers what they want you to do is start an act and play though it. Not just do boss runs over and over again.

Comment: I'm sorry but did you mean that the drop rate is all the same?

Comment: @RenoYeo Updated comment to make a little more sense

Comment: @RenoYeo The drop rates are not the same. Bosses used to have a guaranteed yellow + a lot of other items, and rares did not.  Now Rares/Elites guarantee a Rare item drop at 5 stacks of NV.  Bosses were better before, now Rare & Elite monsters are.