# Are level >60 items dropped in inferno Whimsyshire?

Tags: diablo-iii

Because the Infernal Staff of Herding plans are only accessible at the end of Act 4, are the item level drop rates in Whimsyshire the same as Act 1 Inferno or Act 4 Inferno [as referenced here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74448/which-parts-of-inferno-act-1-actually-drop-ilvl-63-items)?

Comment: Yes, they do drop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For item drop purposes, [Whimsyshire is considered part of Act III/IV by Blizzard](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/uoooj/i_am_we_are_wyatt_cheng_andrew_chambers_and_jay/c4x7elj) in Inferno and Act IV at other difficulties.

Comment: Acts 3 and 4 have different drop-rates, so which is it?

Comment: Acts 3 and 4 have the same droprates.

Comment: @BlueRaja: In Inferno (which the OP was asking about), Act III and IV drop the same levels of gear. I've clarified my answer for other difficulties though.