# Can all items drop anywhere?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 2 there were certain items that were known to only drop off of certain bosses, or in certain acts. I see a lot of information about item level of drops in various acts and difficulties, but not much about which specific drops can be found.

Is there any information about this? For example, where will Natalya's set start dropping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All items can be dropped everywhere, the only diffrence between **acts** is the drop rate of high level items.

See " [Which parts of Inferno Act 1 actually drop ilvl 63 items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74448/which-parts-of-inferno-act-1-actually-drop-ilvl-63-items) " for more details.

Comment: The difference between acts disappears the moment you set the game to MP1 or higher.